# How to use rolling function to predict a trend based on either Simple Moving Average or some other strategy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, data-science

I have a code where I get the 44 days Simple Moving Average of a single stock given it's open, close, high, low, date as follows:

```py
stocks.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace = True)  # Without reverse, recent rolling mean will be either NaN or equal to the exact value

stocks['44-SMA'] = stocks[Close].rolling(44, min_periods = 1).mean()
```

I want to buy stocks where the 44-SMA is rising. I can get that visually but I am writing a code for back testing automation.

My assumption is that **if the current Average price is greater than the average price of last 5 averages ( a week), then there is an uptrend.** ( Is there any other better way to find that?)

So I have written a code like:

```py
def assume_trend(df): # last value -1 is the Latest Stock Price after sorting reverse
    '''
    Perform a rolling operation on the df to find the Current Average and the mean of previous 5 averages
    '''
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        df.loc[i,'Trend Prediction'] = df.loc[-6-i:-i,'Rolling Mean'].mean() < df.loc[i,'Rolling Mean']
```

How can I use `rolling` here as it'll be super fast than the loop here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=np.arange(10), b=np.random.randint(1, 10, 10), c=np.random.randn(10)))
df.loc[:, 'Rolling Mean'] = df.apply(lambda row: df.loc[-5:row.name, 'b'].mean(), axis=1)
df.loc[:, 'Valid'] = df.apply(lambda row: False if row.name < 5 else (False if df.loc[-5:row.name, 'Rolling Mean'].mean() > df.loc[row.name, 'Rolling Mean'] else True), axis=1)
df
```

**Output:**

```
    a   b       c       Rolling Mean    Valid
0   0   5   0.779053    5.000000        False
1   1   6   -0.822965   5.500000        False
2   2   8   0.116101    6.333333        False
3   3   3   -0.716928   5.500000        False
4   4   3   0.077724    5.000000        False
5   5   6   0.235477    5.166667        False
6   6   5   -0.198586   5.142857        False
7   7   7   0.625347    5.375000        False
8   8   7   0.798292    5.555556        True
9   9   5   -0.369337   5.500000        True
```

Cheers